# slide show with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

hi every one  just i want to make imsge slide show with help of css,javascript or jquery like

http://www.webguide.nl/internetbureaus/mediaweb-internet-integrators/deltalloyd-regatta.3878.lynkx?pageStart=1.

this is in flash but i want it the image come dynamically from database in php.
can any one help me please .

Comment: Check out:
http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/web-programming/47-javascript/85-30-best-jquery-photo-plugins-sliders-slideshow-galleries-and-scrollers.html
It has links to dozens of JS/jQuery scripts for slideshows. We can't walk you through from zero to done though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice jquery plugin that might be interesting for you:

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

And an example how to add slides dynamically (found in the 'even more demos' section):

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/add.html?v2

regards,
harpax

Answer (score 0):

try this http://static.flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery I would recommend jQuery cycle.  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/.  It's very extensible and should be able to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look at [loxiastudio.com](http://www.loxiastudio.com/en)
I've made a couple of slide shows on the site, in both Flash and jQuery. They look great!
If you need help getting the slide show onto your site the help section has some really handy tutorials.